# Mysql use of index in case when syntax

Tags: mysql, indexing, case

I'm writing a query that updates with the following syntax:

```
UPDATE foo SET col1 = CASE col2
                      WHEN 1 THEN 3
                      WHEN 2 THEN 9
                       ...
                      ELSE col1 END
WHERE col2 IN (1,2...)
```

Note that there can be thousands of WHEN THEN cases. EXPLAIN shows that PK will be used for IN clause, but how does the database compute the CASE/WHEN after it filters based on IN clause - does it scan all them or use a hash? I don't think this would be explicit in an EXPLAIN (for example without the IN clause).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of thousands of case when statements, create another table in your database (let's name it keyValueTable) and let one column be the `when` (key) and the other one the `then` (value):

```
id      colkey     value
 1       1       3
 2       2       9
```

make `colkey` unique and set an index on it, then query the database like

```
 UPDATE foo SET col1 = (
 SELECT value from keyValueTable 
 INNER JOIN foo ON keyValueTable.colkey = foo.col1 
 LIMIT 1
 ) 
 WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 2):

The `CASE` expression will be tediously walked through for each row not filtered by the `WHERE`.  There is no optimization, since the `WHEN` values could be arbitrary expressions, not simple constants like in your case.

This might be faster, assuming you have an index on col2:

```
UPDATE foo SET col1 = 3 WHERE col2 = 1;
UPDATE foo SET col1 = 9 WHERE col2 = 2;
...
```